# How Do I Get the Selected DataRow in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, ado.net, datagridview

I have a DataTable bound to a DataGridView.  I have FullRowSelect enabled in the DGV.  Is there a way to get the selected row as a DataRow so that I can get strongly typed access to the selected row's values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it w/o a BindingSource, here is how to do it with one:

```
var drv = bindingSoure1.Current as DataRowView;
if (drv != null)
  var row = drv.Row as MyRowType;
```

Answer (score 28):

```
DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)dgv1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem
DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row
```

Comment: Hm… For me the selected row have «DataBoundItem» being null.

Comment: @Hi-Angel you're not using data binding, then.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by getting following property:

```
this.dataGridView.SelectedRows
```

One obtains a collection of type: **DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection**. It contains items of type: **DataGridViewRow**.

Then one can get bounditem with ones own type in following way:

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection list = this.dataGridViewInventoryRecords.SelectedRows;
MyType selectedItem = (MyType)list[0].DataBoundItem; //[0] ---> first item
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to directly cast your selected row into the strongly typed row that was bound to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle); `        
if (row != null)
{
     XtraMessageBox.Show(row["ID"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bound your datagridview to a table or view in a database, you can get the data out as a strongly-typed object.

This answer is for a Windows form that connected to a database using a DataSet at design time. Example name is DataSet1, and example table name is Customer_Info.

```
// cast the data bound item to DataRowView so you have
// access to "Row", which
// has the actual data for the row in typed fields. 
DataRowView drv = dgv.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
// run the code and look at the debugger value of drv.Row -- 
// the type will be shown
// which is the type created by the data binding, representing 
// your table or view
//{YourDataSetName.YourTableOrViewType} tmpTableData = drv.Row as {YourDataSetName.YourTableOrViewType};
DataSet1.Customer_InfoRow tmpTableData = drv.Row as DataSet1.Customer_InfoRow;
```

This link is the answer. I hope I have added clarity and an example above. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f252e395-58e6-4703-ba7b-0740efcbecf3/can-i-convert-the-selected-row-in-a-bound-datagridview-to-a-typed-datarow?forum=winformsdatacontrols

This link shows data programmatically added to the data source, not pulling that data from an existing database. This got me part of the way to the answer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wszzzc7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have strongly typed access to a datagridview if a tableadapter is not being used inside the dataset.

To have access to strongly typed variables when a datagridview is bound to a datatable through a bindingsource, do as follow:

Create a New Project.

Insert a DataSet named ds1 and a DataTable named dt99 with columns named DataColumn1 and DataColumn2, both string type.

[image]

Add a datagridView to the main form and bind it to the dt99

[image]

So that the dt99BindingSource connects the datagridview and the datatable

[image]

Add and event handler for the Selection Change of the datagridview, and insert the following piece of code

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
  ds1.dt99Row d= ((ds1.dt99Row)((DataRowView)dt99BindingSource.Current).Row);

  Debug.WriteLine(d.DataColumn1 + " " + d.DataColumn2);
```

}

Now you have strongly typed variables (d.DataColumn1 and d.DataColumn2) to access the cells being selected on the datagridview

Another interesting feature is that a datatable inserted inside a dataset provides a set of public classes that helps a lot when handling datatables, for example

```
        private void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds1.dt99.Adddt99Row("K", "B");
        ds1.dt99.Adddt99Row("L", "D");
        ds1.dt99.Adddt99Row("M", "F");
        ds1.dt99.Adddt99Row("N", "H");

        ds1.dt99Row dr = ds1.dt99.Newdt99Row();
        dr.DataColumn1 = "X";
        dr.DataColumn2 = "Y";
        ds1.dt99.Adddt99Row(dr);

    }
```