# Datagridview error when trying to open a form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using this code to open a form.  This same code opens other forms all over my application but in this case it is causing an error and I am not sure why.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
  waterDataSet.DEMRow SelectedRow;

  **SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)waterDataSetBindingSource.Current;**
  SelectedRow = (waterDataSet.DEMRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

  frmWater WaterForm = new frmWater(this);
  WaterForm.LoadWaterAcct(SelectedRow.WATER_ACCOUNT, null);
  WaterForm.Show();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
>     Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

The datagridview is being populated by this:

```
public void LoadWaterAcct(String waterAcct, String tableName)
{
  aRTableAdapter.FillByWaterAct(waterDataSet.AR, waterAcct);
}
```

The error is being triggered by the bolded line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the `dataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` should contain the data. Then you can:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  var selRow = this.yourDataGridView.SelectedRows.FirstOrDefault();
  // or
  // var selRow = this.yourDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

  if (selRow != null) {
    var selRowData = selRow.DataBoundItem as waterDataSet.DEMRow;
    if (selRowData != null) {
      frmWater WaterForm = new frmWater(this);
      WaterForm.LoadWaterAcct(selRowData.WATER_ACCOUNT, null);
      WaterForm.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

hope that helps you...

Comment: punker76 thanks for the response.  When I use that code selRowData always comes up as null so the form does not open.  Any ideas?

Comment: @korrowan can you post what selRow.DataBoundItem holds? which type is it?

Comment: can you be more specific as I am not sure what DataBoundItem does or what it is supposed to hold.

Comment: no it is not null.  It shows the correct Object ID and has the table information among other things but it is definitely not null.

Comment: @korrowan perhaps this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/895785/920384 another question is, what is your datasource of the datagridview? datatable? bindingsource? thats my last questions for you.... sorry if i could not help you