# Remove last item in datagridview with another form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I have two form in my project, Form1 and Form2. In Form1 is a datagridview and a button, like shown in this pic:

[image: Form1]

If click button1 in Form1, it will show Form2. In Form2 there is a second button. I want to remove the last item in listview on Form1 if I click the button on form2.

Form1 code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 fm = new Form2(dataGridViewData);
    fm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form2 code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewData.SelectedRows - 1; i++)
        {
            dataGridViewData.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewData.SelectedRows[i]);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are having difficulties with passing that `dataGridViewData` to `Form2`? Am I right? If it is so, then you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/passing-values-between-windows-forms-c-sharp, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916215/c-sharp-add-label-from-form2/32916403#32916403, here I answered how to access controls from another form.

Comment: @EugenePodskal thanks for your suggestion. but is not that used to get the value of the listbox and textbox? what if applied in datagridview ? .

Comment: @Underdog I doubt that there is anything radically different between dealing with one or another type of control in such a manner. If it is nonetheless so, then tell us the exact issues.

Comment: Check the comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162871/delete-last-row-in-datagridview